# Help to find the Integrating factor of the following differential equation and solve it.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(10-6y+e^{-3x})dx-2dy=0$

My text book says the solution -

Integrating factor : $e^{3x}$

Solution : $10e^{3x}-6ye^{x}+3x=c$

Can anyone show me how it is obtained?

Answer (score 1):

$$2\frac{dy}{dx}=10-6y+e^{-3x}$$

$$2\frac{dy}{dx}+6y=10+e^{-3x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+3y=5+\frac{1}{2}e^{-3x}$$

This is a first order linear ODE. The coefficient of $y$ is $3$.

Hence an integrating factor is $\exp(\int 3 dx)=\exp(3x)$.

$$\exp(3x)\frac{dy}{dx}+3\exp(3x) y=5\exp(3x)+\frac12$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\exp(3x)y)=5\exp(3x)+\frac12$$

The remaining tasks are just regular integration.

Edit:

Suppose the integrating factor is  $u(x,y)$.

$$u(x,y)(10-6y+\exp(-3x)) dx -2 u(x,y) dy =0$$

We want the equation to be exact:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}(10-6y+\exp(-3x))-6u(x,y)=-2\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}$$

Let choose $\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$, that is let $u$ be a function of $x$ only.

Hence $$3u(x)=\frac{du}{dx}.$$

Now, you should be able to solve for $u(x)=\exp(3x)$.

Our solution is of the form of $G(x,y)=d$ where $d$ is a constant,

$$G_x = \exp(3x) (10-6y+\exp(-3x))$$

$$G_y=-2\exp(3x))$$

Now, you just have to solve for $G$. Are you able to take it from here?

Comment: Can you show a different solution by using the exactness of this ode. Because we haven't covered the Linear method right now.

Comment: edited my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Rewrite the equation as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+3y=5+\frac{e^{-3x}}{2}.$$
Now the integrating factor is 
$$I.F.=....$$
I'm sure you can complete it.